Why does Parcel build fail with `Module '<imported package name>' is not exported from the '<imported package name>' package`?
I have set up a reproduction of this error on Github. Please check it out.
The gist of the problem is that I'm trying to use a package which declares its exports in its package.json like this:
{
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "svelte": "./lib/index.js",
      "types": "./lib/index.d.ts"
    }
  }
}

Importing anything from this package fails with the following error from Parcel:

@parcel/resolver-default: Module 'imported package name' is not exported from the 'imported package name' package

I realise that Parcel's dependency resolver requires that I enable handling of this type of exports declaration by adding the following to my package.json:
{
  "@parcel/resolver-default": {
    "packageExports": true
  }
}

What am I missing? Check out the linked Github repo for a working reproduction of the error and a detailed example.
